# Injecting a new class into the coffeescript inheritance chain

Tags: coffeescript

I have three coffeescript classes, set up like this:

```
class A
class C extends A
class B
```

so that the prototype chain looks like this:

```
A -> C
B
```

and I need the prototype chain to look like this:

```
A -> B -> C
```

The catch being that I can't touch the definitions of A and C.

What I'd like to do is make an inject function that can be called like this:

```
inject B, C
```

that injects B into C's prototype chain before A, and then set up B's prototype chain to whatever C's was before the injection.

I thought this would be simple, something like

```
C extends (B extends C.prototype)
```

But unfortunately, things aren't quite that simple, due to all the prototype/__super__ magic that coffeescript does. Does anyone know how to inject into the prototype chain such that it's basically like you said `class C extends B` and `class B extends A` in the first place?

Many thanks.

Clarification: The below code DOES NOT WORK, because the properties fail to be copied over.

```
class A
  foo: 1
class B
  bar: 2
class C extends A
  baz: 3

B extends A
C extends B

c = new C
console.log c.foo
console.log c.bar
console.log c.baz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Update:** I originally answered that `C extends B; B extends A` would work. This does indeed make `C instanceof B` and `B instanceof A` become `true`, but it doesn't copy prototypal properties as desired. So, I've rewritten the answer.]

Let's walk through this:

```
class A
  foo: 1
class B
  bar: 2
class C extends A
  baz: 3
```

At this point, `C::foo` is 1 and `C::baz` is 3. If we then run

```
C extends B
```

that overwrites `C`'s existing prototype with an instance of `B` (`child.prototype = ...`), so only `C::bar` is defined.

This doesn't happen when we use the `class X extends Y` syntax because properties are attached to `X`'s prototype only after its prototype is overwritten. So, let's write a wrapper around `extends` that saves existing prototype properties, then restores them:

```
inherits = (child, parent) ->
  proto = child::
  child extends parent
  child::[x] = proto[x] for own x of proto when x not of child::
  child
```

Applying this to our example:

```
inherits B, A
inherits C, B

console.log new C instanceof B, new B instanceof A  # true, true
console.log B::foo, B::bar, B::baz  # 1, 2, undefined
console.log C::foo, C::bar, C::baz  # 1, 2, 3
```

If you'd like to learn more about the inner workings of CoffeeScript classes, you might want to check out [my book on CoffeeScript](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript), published by the fine folks at PragProg. :)

Comment: I tried this, and it sets up the constructor chain correctly, but it fails to copy over the properties. (See the edit on my original question.) Is it safe to just do a _.extends / __hasprop test? I wasn't sure, because it looks like __extends should already be doing this, which is about the point I realized that I have no idea what I'm doing. :-)

Comment: @So8res Right you are. I've rewritten my answer.

Comment: Thanks! One more quick question - is there any way to access A through C so that I can remove one more line of boilerplate?

Comment: @So8res As I mentioned in my original answer, you can write `A.__super__.constructor` to get `A`'s superclass (initially, `C`).